# What does this line mean in CSS?

Tags: css, syntax, background, background-size

What does this line mean in CSS ?

```css
#ffffff url(https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1830348/15354890/1442159a-1cf0-11e6-92b1-b861dadf1750.jpg) no-repeat center center / cover
```

I am trying to figure it out. In [W3S](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp) it says the following about the structure but I can't seem to see what the '/'  and how do other attributes match this structure.

```css
background: bg-color bg-image position/bg-size bg-repeat bg-origin bg-clip bg-attachment initial|inherit;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This line

```css
background: #ffffff url(...) no-repeat center center / cover;
```

Actually is the shorthand version for:

```css
background-color: #ffffff;
background-image: url(...);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
```

The `/` is valid CSS, see the [formal syntax on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background).

Comment: Is that only applicable to FireFox?

Comment: No, it's not. See [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) on MDN.

Answer (score 4):

Well if you split it up, you'll see that it's reading the following in order:

`background-color | background-image | background-repeat | background-position | background-size`

Comment: Shorthand works and no the `/cover` is not invalid. It is the background size.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images) - `cover` is a special value for scaling images:

> The cover value specifies that the background image should be sized so that it is as
>   small as possible while ensuring that both dimensions are greater than
>   or equal to the corresponding size of the container.

Here's their [sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/)

Answer (score 2):

It means a white background is covered by this image; https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1830348/15354890/1442159a-1cf0-11e6-92b1-b861dadf1750.jpg, it is centrally aligned and will stretch to fit the width or height, whichever is largest, whilst mainting its proportions.

Comment: not "or" -- cover stretches to fit both width **and** height and crops extra.